# Quickly flashing pop up keeps annoying me how do I find out what process it is?

Tags: macos

On Sonoma, I have this very quick and random pop-up that opens very often, several times a minute and it's a very small dialog that closes just as fast as it opens and I can never read it or find it in Activity Monitor. Please tell me where I can find some logs or something that will help me find out what it is so I can find a way to eventually make it stop popping up all the time, it's slowly driving me crazy and I prefer to find out what it is then to wipe the mac clean first.

After looking at the frame-by-frame screen capture, it appears that it is the verification system it says:

`Verifying "_struct.cpython37m-darwin.so..."`

After looking at the logs it appears like something is putting this binary in `/private/tmp` and I guess opening it and causing this pop-up. Any other ideas on how to stop this?

Comment: Run a screengrab video [cmd/shift/5] so you pause it to read.

Comment: Amazing idea @Tetsujin it appears for ONE FRAME! It says "Verifying _struct.cpython37m-darwin.so..." so it looks like the app security/verification. I need to record more to see if it's other things but for now I am looking at the logs

Comment: I have the a similar problem: ` Verifying shm-id-FBA9... ` This popup keeps flashing every 30 seconds or so. Every time it flashes it also steals the focus for half a second. I tried deleting the /Library/Cache and tried reinstalling Sonoma, to no avail.
I also tried running `find` on the entire drive and wasn't able to find the file mentioned. This is driving me crazy.

Comment: What sort of python work do either of you do? Any third party apps that didn’t come from the Mac app store? @Tomer

Comment: @Tomer I have the same exact problem, Verifying shm-id-... any luck resolving it?

Comment: @bmike my problem is not necessarily python related. Yes, I have lots of apps not from the app store (as does everyone, no?). I tried removing some of them, especially ones with auto-updaters, such as Google's and Microsoft's, but it didn't help.

Comment: A response from Erlang maintainers: https://github.com/erlang/otp/issues/8043#issuecomment-1906746914

Comment: Here's also an ElixirForum thread: https://elixirforum.com/t/popup-appears-for-a-fraction-of-a-second-whenever-a-mix-task-is-run-verifying-shm-id-f8bd8e/61169

Answer (score 3):

The "Verifying shm-id-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" case appears to be due to [use of asmjit](https://github.com/asmjit/asmjit/blob/03b784c9fe16123974de14047cbf68336b232234/src/asmjit/core/virtmem.cpp#L560), a JIT framework used in numerous projects.  Presumably the combination with some new security behavior in Sonoma leads to these annoying popups.

The most expedient workaround in my case was just disabling it entirely (rebuilding the stuff which was using it to instead omit it).  (Would be nice to influence its behavior more dynamically but I couldn't quickly figure out how...)

Comment: Not sure I follow, how do we disable it entirely, and how do we rebuild stuff that's using it when we don't know what's using it?

Comment: To find out who might be using it, I looked at the "asmjit in Open Source" section on their [website](https://asmjit.com/). In my case, I think it was because I had erlang and rabbitmq installed on my mac. `brew uninstall erlang rabbitmq` looks like it might have fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianLong. Though sadly I can't uninstall Erlang, I work with it.

Comment: Any other suggestions for running RabbitMQ without this annoying bug?

Answer (score 2):

Not a solution, but a workaround: I created a new user and moved all my stuff to the new user. It's a serious headache, because I had to deal with changing permissions on files and folders all over the place, but at least it works.